# Which US services allow small/micro-payments using a credit card?

Tags: credit-card

I'm looking for some US-based service that allows having frequent and small payments via credit card. Ideally it should be some popular or mainstream service.

A hypothetical example of a good solution would be a hosting provider where I can rent a virtual shared server for $30/month but will get my credit card charged $1 each day.

The nature of the service isn't that important for me, as long as there are very cheap tiers to it.

Comment: I'm trying to think of a legitimate reason for someone to want to be charged money every day, but not care what kind of goods or services they get in exchange.  So far, I haven't succeeded.

Comment: You could try something like mosso.com or amazon.com which will let you pay for servers on an hourly basis. You still get billed at the end of the month, but you only pay for what you use, not the entire month.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any and it is unlikely that you will be able to find one.  Most credit card processors charge a flat fee plus percentage.  The flat fee is typically in the 35 cent range making the cost of doing business, in the manner you are suggesting, astronomical.

Also what you are suggesting is contrary to best practices as hosting services, and many other industries, offer deep discounts when making a single payment for an extended period of time.

This is not very helpful, but I think it is unrealistic to find what you are suggesting.

Comment: +1. Micropayments are still essentially an unsolved problem, and the issues are practical rather than just policy.